# Chaining synchronous Redux actions and consuming in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two Redux actions which need to execute synchronously. `requestStripeToken` is called in my component (signupComponent.js), but in order to get a Stripe Token I first need to make a call to an internal API to get the current Stripe Key (as this changes depending on the environment and SKU). Both of these functions are set up as separate actions in my actions file (actions.js).

The issue I have it that I am not sure how to consume the `requestStripeToken` function in my component. I don't know whether it is an issue with what I am returning in the `requestStripeToken` action or whether the Promise consumption logic in my component needs to change. Note I am using `redux-thunk` middleware.

```
// actions.js

export function requestStripeToken(values) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const { cardNumber, cvc, nameOnCard, expiryMonth, expiryYear, billingLine1, billingLine2, billingCity, billingState, billingZip, billingCountry } = values;

    // We need to get the Stripe key before we can request a Stripe Token
    return dispatch(getStripeSecretKey())
    // Curried function necessary as getStripeSecretKey returns the fetch Promise inside of function(dispatch) ?
    .then(() => (key) => {
      console.log(key);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey(key);
        Stripe.card.createToken({
          number: cardNumber,
          cvc,
          name: nameOnCard,
          exp_month: expiryMonth,
          exp_year: expiryYear,
          address_line1: billingLine1,
          address_line2: billingLine2,
          address_city: billingCity,
          address_state: billingState,
          address_zip: billingZip,
          address_country: billingCountry,
        }, (status, response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            dispatch(addNotification({
              message: response.error.message,
              level: `error`,
              autoDismiss: 0,
            }));
            reject();
          }
          return resolve(response.id);
        });
      });
    });
  };
}

export function getStripeSecretKey() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch(`${getAPIPath}api/stripeKey`, {
      method: `GET`,
      credentials: `include`,
      headers: {
        Accept: `application/json`,
      },
    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      });
    })
    .catch(response => response.json().then((res) => {
      dispatch(addNotification({
        message: res.message,
        level: `error`,
        autoDismiss: 0,
      }));
      throw res;
    }));
  };
}
```

`console.log(key)` in this file never gets called.

```
// signupComponent.js

handleCreateAccountSubmit = (values) => {
  this.setState({ submitting: true });
  // We need the Stripe Token before we can signup the user so needs to be synchronous
  this.props.actions.requestStripeToken(values)
  .then((stripeToken) => {
    console.log(stripeToken);
    this.signupUser(values, stripeToken);
  })
  .catch(() => this.stopSubmission());
}
```

`console.log(stripeToken)` in this file returns:

```
ƒ (key) {
        console.log(key);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          Stripe.setPublishableKey(key);
          Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: cardNumber,
…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return Promises in your getStripeSecretKey() as well.
Dispatch returns what the action creator returns, so if you do:

`export function getStripeSecretKey() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch(`${getAPIPath}api/stripeKey`, {
      method:`GET`,
      credentials:`include`,
      headers: {
        Accept:`application/json`,
      },
    })
    .then(handleErrors) // also return Promise.reject() in errors 
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json().then((res) => { // DONT BREAK RETURN CHAIN
        return Promise.resolve(res.data); // RESOLVE
      });
    })
    .catch(response => response.json().then((res) => {
      dispatch(addNotification({
        message: res.message,
        level:`error`,
        autoDismiss: 0,
      }));
      return Promise.reject(res); // REJECT
    }));
  };
}`

Comment: Returning Promises in `getStripeSecretKey` did the trick. Changing the `requestStripeToken` function like you suggested didn't work, but reverting it back to how I originally had it did work (still returning a Promise).